# Check ruby method values

Tags: ruby, rspec

I have this ruby method. I would like to verify that the current attributes are present and the values are correct. How can I do this using external method?

```
def base_commands
    { currency: 'EUR',
      card_number: '4200000000000000',
      cvv: '123',
      amount: '12345' }
end
```

Quick example:

```
has_children = !base_commands[:currency].nil?
```

But how can I verify the values?

Comment: "how can I verify the values" - `base_commands[:currency] == 'EUR'`

Comment: It depends on what exactly you want to verify and how.

Comment: @MarekLipka can you give example for "are there attributes"?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood you correctly - you mean you want to check for the attribute presence in `base_commands`?

Comment: @MarekLipka correct.

Comment: If you're using Rails (or `activesupport` at least), you can do something like this: `base_commands[:currency].present?`.

Comment: @MarekLipka: this will fail for falsey values, though. Mere presence of the attribute is better checked like this: `base_commands.key?(:currency)`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev you're right, of course. I guess that's why I asked about what exactly did the Autor expect from this check. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I need just to verify that attributes are present. Can you show me complete example?

Comment: @PeterPenzov: I think you should be able to produce one yourself, by combining hints from the comments above.

Answer (score 1):

Note that with `h[:x].nil?`, you do not necessarily test, whether the hash contains an element :x or not, because `{x: nil}.nil?` would also evaluate to *true*. To test, whether or not a key is present, you have to use `h.has_key?(:x)`.

Assuming that you have a hash `h` and want to verify that it contains all the keys which are present in the hash returned by the method `base_commands`, you could do something like `base_commands.keys.all? {|k| h.has_key?(k)}`.

To test whether the value belonging to a key is as expected, you have to think about what equality means. In your case, the hash which is returned from the method `base_commands` has only strings as values, so in your case, simple equality is most likely what you want: `h[:currency] == base_commands[:currency]`, or in whatever way you want to verify it.

In the general case, you could have arbitrary objects as values, and here you have to think about how to regard equality. The default `==` operator might use object identity, and if this is not what you want, you would have to define your own equality method.

Answer (score 0):

RSpec has an [`include` matcher](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/3-7/docs/built-in-matchers/include-matcher):

```
def base_commands
  { currency: 'EUR', card_number: '4200000000000000', cvv: '123', amount: '12345' }
end

RSpec.describe(base_commands) do
  it { is_expected.to include(:currency) }                    # key only
  it { is_expected.to include(currency: 'EUR') }              # key and value
  it { is_expected.to include(currency: 'EUR', cvv: '123') }  # multiple values
end
```